# Delete from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

i have an arraylist called Module, i want to create a method that will delete a module from the ArrayList based on the index passed as the parameter.  this is what i have so far but it isn't working.  any suggestions please (beginner)?  Simon

```
/**
 * This method deletes a module object from the ArrayList
 * @param theModule The module object that will be deleted from the ArraList
 */
public void deleteModule (Module theModule)
{
    modules.delete(theModule);
}
```

Comment: what you mean by "isn't working"? any error? please add more code, such as the definition for `modules`.

Comment: (Probably the best) Q&A on SO about overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/

Comment: You're not passing an index as the parameter - you're passing the object itself.

Comment: I have a question... do you use an ide and if so doesn't it show you the compile error?

Answer (score 7):

Try the [remove](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
boolean success = someList.remove(someObject);
```

Be sure to implement `equals` and `hashcode`, otherwise SO members and your Unit Tests won't be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Delete doesn't seem to be an ArrayList method.

Try using remove, and don't forget to override the equals method.

Take a look at the [api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)):

> Removes the first occurrence of the
> specified element from this list, if
> it is present. If the list does not
> contain the element, it is unchanged.
> More formally, removes the element
> with the lowest index i such that
> (o==null ? get(i)==null :
> o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element
> exists). Returns true if this list
> contained the specified element (or
> equivalently, if this list changed as
> a result of the call).

Comment: thanks to you all for the feedback.  looks like it's working ok now.  Simon

Answer (score 0):

In the example the method is taking a `Module` object not the index so you need to get the index of the object `theModule` first then use that index to remove the object from the list:

```
public void deleteModule (Module theModule)
{
    int moduleIndex = modules.indexOf(theModule);
    modules.remove(moduleIndex);
}
```

However it not really necessary to do this, the ArrayLists support a remove method that take the object to remove as a parameter:

```
public void deleteModule (Module theModule)
{
    modules.remove(theModule);
}
```

The problem in your case is that you are calling **modules.delete(theModule);** instead of **modules.remove(theModule);**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can't really see how `Module` is an index.

The correct way of removing element from ArrayList based on index is:

```
//ie: 
int index = 1;
modules.remove(index); //Will remove the second element in the arraylist
```

If you want to remove the `Module` which is in the modules arraylist, you can do this by sending the module as parameter to the remove method

```
modules.remove(module);
```

However you must ensure Module has correctly implemented hashCode() and equals().
Normally all standard IDE's can generate this for you.